# SSL not working in Wildfly

Tags: ssl, wildfly

I checked Wildfly docs and also other sources, but I just can't get SSL to work in Wildfly.

I exported my keystore file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out output_cert.pfx -inkey domain.key -in domain.crt -certfile ../ca.crt
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore output_cert.pfx  -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore output_store.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

I got no errors in the commands above.

Then I configured standalone.xml.

```
<security-realm name="ssl-realm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <keystore path="SSL/output_store.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="mypassword" alias="1" key-password="mypassword"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

And I added this to the default-server.

```
<https-listener name="https" security-realm="ssl-realm" socket-binding="https"/>
```

I started Wildfly, no errors appeared in the log and I found this line:

```
10:17:58,475 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on my_ip:8443
```

Then I deployed an application to the root (/) web context and tried to access it through my_ip:8443, https://my_ip, my_domain:8443, https://my_domain.

However I always get a page with the message "The connection was reset". If I change the URL to my_ip:8080, the application can be found through http.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It was a really silly mistake.

I had to try to access https://my_domain:8443.

I had tried all combinations, except the correct one.